# Where to configure Rails 3 cache_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to configure Rails 3 cache_store with something like this in environments/development.rb:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, {:size => 64.megabytes, :expires_in => 5.minutes}
```

But when i start server i get:

```
undefined method `megabytes' for 64:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Probably something is not loaded yet.

My question is: where is the right place to configure it them? Where should i place this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ActionController::Base.cache_store =` and place in an initializer file (create an rb file in config/initializers)

Answer (score 16):

Or else add this line

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/bytes'
```

before

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, {:size => 64.megabytes, :expires_in => 5.minutes}
```